# How to run shell commands of a conda environment on Jupyter Notebook following installation of the IPython kernel?

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook, ipython

As the title say, I would like to know how to run shell commands (or if it is at all possible) on Jupyter Notebook, of a package that has been installed on a conda environment. I have created a new environment and then installed the IPython kernel on that environemnt in order to be able to run one session of Jupyter Notebook and work on my two environments (in different notebooks). However, when I try to run a shell command of a particular package, I get an error message saying that it cannot be found. I suspect that this is because Jupyter was opened in the base environment (which I would like to do, for simplicity), where the package does not exist. In other words, I suspect that although I can change my environment to the new one, the shell commands are seemingly still run on the base environment.

To give an overview, here is my scenario:

```
conda activate newenv
conda install <package>
python -m ipykernel install --user --name newenv --display-name "Python (newenv)"
```

Then, I open Jupyter Notebook. Create a new notebook, and I can import and work on  without any issues. However, the package in question has a command line interface, and some functions are more easily handled through it. If I try to run  directly on the Terminal, there are no issues. However, when I call `!<package>`, I get the following error:
`/usr/bin/sh: <package>': command not found`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.